# What is the correct If Then Else formula to use in this situation?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

```
Column A           Column B.      Visa.      MasterCard
5429********6324.    12.75
4728********7632.    75.16
```

Column A and B represent the format in which I receive downloaded credit card payment info from the payment processor.

Column A is the beginning and end if the customer's credit card number with the numbers in between represented by *'s.

MasterCard credit card numbers begin with 5.

Visa credit card numbers begin with 4.

I need a formula that will take the value of Column B and place it in the appropriate Column C or D depending on which type of credit card it is. The asterisks seem to be the problem and I don't know how yo get around it. Is there a formula something like =IFA1 starts with 5, B1,0  and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use something like this in Column C:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="4",B1,"")
```

And, in column D:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="5",B1,"")
```

"LEFT" takes the left-most character of a string.  In this example, the string is in "A1" (but change to whatever reference you need), and I'm specifying "1", to retrieve only one character from the left of A1.

If the left-most character is 4 or 5, depending on the formula for Visa or MasterCard, then copy the value from B1.

Comment: That should perfectly!  Had no idea that was an option and all my searching didn't turn it up. Thank you so much!